# JFreeChart - Vertical Line Chart

Tags: jfreechart, linechart

HI how to create a chart like http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/images/VerticalLine.png. Using XYPlot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Many charts let you specify the [`PlotOrientation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/class-use/PlotOrientation.html) in the corresponding chart factory, but [`createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) is not one of them. As an alternative, you can create your own variation using the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1865) as a guide.

Addendum: As @Gavin comments, `PlotOrientation.VERTICAL` is the default for `XYPlot, so you'd do something like this (untested):

```
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, timeAxis, valueAxis, null);
plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: A bit more specific, you'll be looking for `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL` to get the graph plotting from the top of the screen to the bottom.